# Get textbox.text of a form

Tags: c#

I searched a lot for this but i did not found an answer that works. This is what i am lookig for.

I have a window with a textbox. When i push a button i make a instance of a class and then i want to read te textbox.text into the class.
This is what i tried:

Textbox leave event (name textbox = textBox_klantnaam):

```
klantNaam = textBox_klantnaam.Text;
```

In the same form i have a property:

```
public string klantNaam
{
    get { return textBox_klantnaam.Text; }
    set { textBox_klantnaam.Text = value;  }  
}
```

onclick button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class_licentiemanager SchrijfLicentieBestand = new Class_licentiemanager();
    SchrijfLicentieBestand.schrijfLicBestand();
}
```

The class which neeeds to read the textbox.text and then write it to a file
the property "klantNaam" seems to be empty????

```
namespace Opzet_Leeg_Framework
{
    class Class_licentiemanager
    {
        Class_Logging logging = new Class_Logging();
        public static Form_Licentiemanager Licentiemanager = new Form_Licentiemanager();

        public void schrijfLicBestand()
        {

            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Settings.applicatiePad + Form1.SettingsMap + Form1.Applicatienaam + ".lic")) 
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        w.WriteLine("test line, works fine");
                        w.WriteLine("Naam klant : " + Licentiemanager.klantNaam);  //Empty , no line ???
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        logging.witeToLog("FOUT", "Het opslaan van het licentiebestand is mislukt", 1);
                        logging.witeToLog("FOUT", "Melding : ", 1);
                        logging.witeToLog("FOUT", e.ToString(), 1);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    w.Close();
                    w.Dispose();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the value to that class, and not create another form instance inside of it. When you write `new Form_Licentiemanager` then you're creating an new instance of that form and not reusing the same instance, so the value on that new instance is still empty. To fix that, do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class_licentiemanager SchrijfLicentieBestand = new Class_licentiemanager();
    SchrijfLicentieBestand.schrijfLicBestand(klantNaam);
}
```

And change your code:

```
class Class_licentiemanager
{
    Class_Logging logging = new Class_Logging();
    public void schrijfLicBestand(string klantNaam)
    {
       // same code here ......
                    w.WriteLine("test line, works fine");
                    w.WriteLine("Naam klant : " + klantNaam); 
       // same code here ......  
    }           
}
```